# How do you stop the console from taking user input until you need it?

Tags: python

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
num2 = input("enter a number: ")
result = float(num1) + int(num2)
```

How do I stop the user from entering numbers before they're needed?

Comment: I remember when the ability to "type ahead" was almost a selling point. =)

Comment: It is normal behavior for console programs to allow typeahead. That's the default behavior unless you go out of your way to disable it, which most programs do not. It's possible to prevent it but I wouldn't bother.